# Laravel separate read/write operations for Redis?

Tags: laravel, redis

I have a Redis cluster running inside Kubernetes. A Redis cluster can only have 1 master and N slaves. Is it possible to have multiple Redis connections inside Laravel for reading and writing? so I can write to the master and read from a slave. It's possible for 'normal' databases:

```
'mysql' => [
  'read' => [
     'host' => ['192.168.1.1'],
   ],
  'write' => [
     'host' => ['196.168.1.2'],
   ],
  '....'    => .....
]
```

Is there anyway to achieve this for Redis?

Thankyou,

Answer (score 6):

You can change which connection is used with the [`connection`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/redis#interacting-with-redis) method which will return a Redis instance, e.g:

```
$redis = Redis::connection('read');
$redis->get('example');
```

You would configure the different connections in the same way you would for MySQL.

```
'redis' => [

    'client' => 'predis',

    'default' => [
        'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
        'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', 6379),
        'database' => 0,
    ],

    'read' => [
        'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
        'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', 6380),
        'database' => 0,
    ],

],
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer, I was searching for an easier implementation without the 'overhead' of selecting which connection to use. I think this is the only solution for now.